# Create a scenekit edge so objects disappear as they pass it?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, gamekit

I have a swift iOS game with part of the iPad screen as a board.  I have some node's on the board that I move with touch. As they get to the edge of the board I want them to disappear as they go past the edge.  How do I create a rectangular "board" in the middle of my iPad that has edges such that when an object is moved past the edge it disappears? It does it at the edge of the iPad screen, but I want a section of my iPad to be the board, not the whole iPad screen.
Thanks.